# Control for previous day values when doing across day analysis with generalized estimating equations?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-estimating-equations

I am a graduate student and have a question regarding generalized estimating equation analysis. When conducting across day analysis with GEE, with variable a on day $x$ predicting variable $b$ on day $x+1$, is it necessary to control for previous day's values for variable $b$, or is this correlation already accounted for with the GEE technique? 
Your comments and references would be much appreciated.